# How to use Excel formula combining replace and match

Tags: excel

I have these sets of values in Excel and I want them to be replaced, please see the attached screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by "replace", but I think what you need is lookup function.

try this Vlookup function:

```
=VLOOKUP(D2,A:B,2,FALSE)
```

You can learn more about [vlookup here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)

Comment: hi guys, im good, i got help from a friend lol, she uses index and match...thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

you can use `vlookup`

follow [this tutorial](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/vlookup.php)

Comment: hi guys, im good, i got help from a friend lol, she uses index and match...thanks again!